# How to handle this function?

Tags: swift, function, for-in-loop

I wanted to wrote a function where street fighters attacking them alternately. Each attack pulls some hearts of. When one of the fighters has 0 hearts, the fight is over. But I don't know how to do this process again and again. This is how my code looks right now:

```
public struct StreetFighter {
    var name: String
    var power: Int
    var defence: Int
    var hearts: Int
    func Attack() {
        print("\(name) is going into the offence...")
    }
    func Blocking() {
        print("\(name) is blocking the attack")
    }
}
var connorMcGregor = StreetFighter(name: "Connor McGregor", power: 8, defence: 7, hearts: 100)
var mikeTyson = StreetFighter(name: "Connor McGregor", power: 9, defence: 6, hearts: 100)
var alisterOverreem = StreetFighter(name: "Alister Overreem", power: 7, defence: 10, hearts: 100)
var khabib = StreetFighter(name: "Khabib", power: 9, defence: 8, hearts: 100)


struct Fight {
    var location: String
    mutating func Round1(firstFighter: StreetFighter,secondFighter: StreetFighter) -> Int {
        firstFighter.Attack()
        if firstFighter.power < secondFighter.defence  {
            secondFighter.Blocking()
            secondFighter.Attack()
        } else {
        secondFighter.hearts - firstFighter.power
            }
            
            if secondFighter.power < firstFighter.defence  {
                firstFighter.Blocking()
            } else {
        firstFighter.hearts - secondFighter.power
            }
        if firstFighter.hearts == 0 || secondFighter.hearts == 0 {
        print("The fight is over!")
        
        }
        return firstFighter.hearts
        return secondFighter.hearts
    }
}

var mma = Fight(location: "New York")
mma.Round1(firstFighter: connorMcGregor, secondFighter: khabib)
```

The problem is that the process stops after the first round. I tried it with for-in or repeat-while loops but without any success.
Can anybody helps me?

Comment: 1. You have 2 return operator - it is wrong at a basic level. You need only 1 return.     2. Why do you need to return hearts? for the second round?                                        3.

Comment: Can you tell me how it should work? Do you want to run 1 function and it must work on all12 rounds? and returns the winner and the last round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may try to move some functions to the `StreetFighter` itself:

```
public struct StreetFighter {
    let name: String
    let power: Int
    let defence: Int
    var hearts = 100 // you can provide a default value

    var isAlive: Bool {
        hearts > 0
    }

    func attack() {
        print("\(name) is going into the offence...")
    }

    mutating func defend(attackingPower: Int) {
        if power > defence {
            hurt(damage: attackingPower)
        } else {
            block()
        }
    }

    private func block() {
        print("\(name) is blocking the attack")
    }

    private mutating func hurt(damage: Int) {
        print("\(name) is hurt")
        hearts -= damage
    }
}
```

Then, add a function in the `Fight` struct with a `while` loop (you can limit the number of rounds there as well):

```
struct Fight {
    let location: String
    var fighter1: StreetFighter
    var fighter2: StreetFighter

    mutating func start() {
        var roundNumber = 0
        while !isFinished && roundNumber < 12 {
            roundNumber += 1
            round()
            print("Round \(roundNumber): \(fighter1.name) - \(fighter1.hearts), \(fighter2.name) - \(fighter2.hearts)")
        }

        print("The fight is over!")
    }

    private mutating func round() {
        fighter1.attack()
        fighter2.defend(attackingPower: fighter1.power)
        fighter2.attack()
        fighter1.defend(attackingPower: fighter2.power)
    }

    private var isFinished: Bool {
        !fighter1.isAlive || !fighter2.isAlive
    }
}
```

Now you can start your fight:

```
let connorMcGregor = StreetFighter(name: "Connor McGregor", power: 8, defence: 7, hearts: 100)
let mikeTyson = StreetFighter(name: "Connor McGregor", power: 9, defence: 6, hearts: 100)
let alisterOverreem = StreetFighter(name: "Alister Overreem", power: 7, defence: 10, hearts: 100)
let khabib = StreetFighter(name: "Khabib", power: 9, defence: 8) // you can use the default `hearts` count

var mma = Fight(location: "New York", fighter1: connorMcGregor, fighter2: khabib)
mma.start()
```

---

Depending on your goal you may want to extract some parts of `Fight` outside. For example the `start` function can return a result (who won) and you can operate on it then.

Comment: Wow that's great thanks! I just have started learning how to code at the big corona lockdown so I'm new at this area but it's a lot of fun! :)